# Hybrid Application with Crosswalk + Cordova + Eclipse

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile-application, crosswalk-runtime

I am getting an issue/error while creating/importing `crosswalk` `cordova` plugin into `eclipse`.

Can any one share a simple steps from scratch for creating `crosswalk` `cordova` app with `eclipse`.

Also tell me which `eclipse` type & version is required.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to Import Crosswalk Lib plugin in Eclipse :-

1. Download CrossWalk from https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/stable/12.41.296.9/arm/crosswalk-webview-12.41.296.9-arm.zip
2. Once the Zip is downloaded extract it and paste it in the same directory where your eclipse project is saved.
3. Now goto Eclipse New -> Import -> Android ->Existing Code into workspace -> goto your location and make sure you donot copy the crosswalk project into your  eclipse workspace.
4. Once Import is done right click on your project click Properties (Alt+Enter) - > Android -> Add -> Choose crosswalk from your workspace and Done..

Comment: this imports only crosswalk to project

Answer (score 0):

I'mnt sure about what you want to say with "importing plugins into eclipse". 
If you want to use plugins you have to use [CLI](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) ( some plugins installation at the end of the page ).

Otherwise, if you want to create your own plugin, follow this [guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide).

Comment: thanks for the CLI help that I know how to add Cordova plugin using CLI. But how to add `Crosswalk` in `Eclipse`?

Comment: dowload [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.html) jars and add it in your project